# how to use props for a component in index.js with react router v6.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Started using react router v6.3 today, and i implemented it on the index.js, and everything works fine when the link is `http://localhost:3000/`, but when i click the link to go to the cart component, it returns an error because the `cart` props is located in the `App.js` not `index.js`, Is there a way to use the props from `App.js` in `index.js`?

```js
index.js
import Cart from ./src/Cart

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <Router>
        <Routes>
            <Route path ="/" element ={<App/}  />
             <Route path ="cart" element ={<Cart cart ={cart}/}  />
        </Routes>
    </Router>
  
);
```

Comment: Add app.js and card.js so we can figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Of course. You should use something like this:

```
<Route path='/' element={<App />}>
    <Route path='ways-of-magic/:way' element={<MagicWay />} />
</Route>
```

And in page Cart take it from url